# How to dynamically use a form in javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I would like to know how I can call a function using the dynamic result of what I typed in a form! I managed to transform this value to be used but when I press the button it doesn't change and stays statically at 0 (as if I hadn't typed anything)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bloco">
      <h1>QUAL É SUA CATEGORIA NO UFC</h1>
      <p id="resultPound">Coloque seu peso e vamos transformar em libras para descobrir em que categoria do UFC você lutaria!</p>
      <form> <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="digite seu peso"><br></form>
      <button>Confirmar</button>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var teste = document.getElementById("fname").value;  
function kilostoPounds(teste) { return ((teste * 2.2046).toFixed()) }
const finalPound = kilostoPounds(teste);


switch (true) {
    case finalPound <= 123:
        document.getElementById("resultPound").innerHTML = `Você seria da categoria <b>Peso Mosca</b>, pois você tem o que equivale a ${finalPound}lb`;
        break;
    case finalPound <= 135:
        document.getElementById("resultPound").innerHTML = `Você seria da categoria <b>Peso Galo</b>, pois você tem o que equivale a ${finalPound}lb`;
        break;
    case finalPound <= 145:
        document.getElementById("resultPound").innerHTML = `Você seria da categoria <b>Peso Pena</b>, pois você tem o que equivale a ${finalPound}lb`;
        break;
    case finalPound <= 155:
        document.getElementById("resultPound").innerHTML = `Você seria da categoria <b>Peso Leve</b>, pois você tem o que equivale a ${finalPound}lb`;
        break;
    case finalPound <= 171:
        document.getElementById("resultPound").innerHTML = `Você seria da categoria <b>Peso Meio Medio</b>, pois você tem o que equivale a ${finalPound}lb`;
        break;
    case finalPound <= 185:
        document.getElementById("resultPound").innerHTML = `Você seria da categoria <b>Peso Medio</b>, pois você tem o que equivale a ${finalPound}lb`;
        break;
    case finalPound <= 205:
        document.getElementById("resultPound").innerHTML = `Você seria da categoria <b>Peso Meio Pesado</b>, pois você tem o que equivale a ${finalPound}lb`;
        break;
    case finalPound <= 265:
        document.getElementById("resultPound").innerHTML = `Você seria da categoria <b>Peso Pesado</b>, pois você tem o que equivale a ${finalPound}lb`;
        break;
    default: document.getElementById("resultPound").innerHTML = "Digite um peso correto";
}
```

Note that if I type, for example, 75 it will give a result and if I type 91 it will show something else

Comment: The switch would need to be inside your method. It does not just keep running. It runs once and is done. So onclick on the button, call a function, run the code

Comment: There's an entire world for you to examine: [DOM events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your JavaScript code inside a function so it can be called later in time

```
function updateValue() {
    // Your Js code here
}
```

And try this on your html

```
<div id="bloco">
  <h1>QUAL É SUA CATEGORIA NO UFC</h1>
  <p id="resultPound">Coloque seu peso e vamos transformar em libras para descobrir em que categoria do UFC você lutaria!</p>
  <form onsubmit="updateValue()"> 
      <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="digite seu peso">
      <br>
      <button>Confirmar</button>
  </form>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</div>
```

- Your button isn't inside the form, so pressing the button won't submit the form
- And the JavaScript is only called when the website is first loaded. Subsequent form submissions now trigger the newly created JavaScript function.

Comment: thank you it worked! would you know if i deleted the number i typed it would return to the initial message? because I put a condition in the switch function of "case finalPound == 0:" but it only works if I press the button

Comment: Yeah, that is expected. You can maybe try this. Remove the button. And change your input tag to this. <input type="text" onchange="changeValue()" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="digite seu peso">  now it instantly changes when you type on the input